# Creating expressions for recursive extraction

Tags: r, recursion, extract, substitution

### Actual question

I'd like to write a little function that allows me to flexibly compose recursive extraction expressions for lists or environments based on the syntactic sugars `[[` and/or `$`:

```
x <- list(a = list(b = 1))

> x[["a"]][["b"]]
[1] 1
```

How could I manage to do this by using `substitute` instead of a combination of `parse` and `eval` (as this is really slow)?

### What I tried

I know how to do this by a combination of `parse` and `eval`, but that's really slow:

```
foo <- function(idx, obj = character(), sep = c("[['", "']][['", "']]")) {
  out <- paste0(sep[1], paste(idx, collapse = sep[2]), sep[3])
  if (length(obj)) {
    out <- paste0(obj, out)
  }
  out
}
> foo(c("a", "b"), "x")
[1] "x[['a']][['b']]"

expr <- parse(text = foo(c("a", "b"), "x"))

> expr
expression(x[['a']][['b']])

> eval(expr)
[1] 1
```

So I turned to `substitute`. While this works fine for most of my tasks where I would like to compose R expressions, I don't know how to use it for this "nested extraction" task:

```
expr <- substitute(assign(X, VALUE),
  list(X = "x_2", VALUE = as.name("letters")))

> expr
assign("x_2", letters)

eval(expr)
> x_2
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u"
[22] "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

expr <- substitute(FUN(X, INDEX),
  list(FUN = as.name('[['), X = as.name("x"), INDEX = "a"))

> expr
x[["a"]]

> eval(expr)
$b
[1] 1
```

### Benchmarking

Here's a comparison of the computational costs:

```
# install.packages("microbenchmark")
require(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
  "1" = {
    expr <- substitute(assign(X, VALUE),
      list(X = "x_2", VALUE = as.name("letters")))
    eval(expr)
  },
  "2" = {
    expr <- substitute(FUN(X, INDEX),
      list(FUN = as.name('[['), X = as.name("x"), INDEX = "a"))
    eval(expr)
  },
  "3" = {
    expr <- parse(text = foo(c("a", "b"), "x"))
    eval(expr)
  }
)

> res
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
    1   3.519   4.1060   6.12306   4.839   5.7185  59.528   100
    2   2.639   3.5190   4.41350   4.105   4.6920  20.820   100
    3 196.765 204.6825 220.33854 212.600 222.8630 505.547   100
```

---

### Update

I came up with a function that would take advantage of `substitute` while also being up to the task of handling the recursive aspect:

```
bar <- function(idx, obj) {
  for (ii in 1:length(idx)) {
    if (ii == 1) {
      X <- as.name("obj")
    } else {
      X <- expr
    }
    INDEX <- idx[ii]
    expr <- substitute(FUN(X, INDEX),
      list(FUN = as.name('[['), X = X, INDEX = INDEX))
  }
  expr
}
```

Then Gabor came along with his answer and made me realize that I think for some unexplainable reason I never used `[[` with more than one index values before. I only did that for `[`. Kind of embarassing ;-). Nevertheless, here's the round-up comparison:

```
require(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
  "1" = {
    expr <- substitute(assign(X, VALUE),
      list(X = "x_2", VALUE = as.name("letters")))
    eval(expr)
  },
  "2" = {
    expr <- substitute(FUN(X, INDEX),
      list(FUN = as.name('[['), X = as.name("x"), INDEX = "a"))
    eval(expr)
  },
  "3" = {
    expr <- parse(text = foo(c("a", "b"), "x"))
    eval(expr)
  },
  "4" = {
    expr <- bar(c("a", "b"), x)
    eval(expr)
  },
  "5" = {
    expr <- substitute(FUN(X, INDEX),
      list(FUN = as.name('[['), X = as.name("x"), INDEX = c("a", "b")))
    eval(expr)
  }
)

>   res
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
    1   3.519   4.3990   5.59530   4.9855   5.865   21.700   100
    2   2.639   3.5190   4.53380   3.8130   4.692   30.790   100
    3 174.772 182.2490 212.85493 196.3250 207.615 1558.576   100
    4  13.489  14.9555  19.50659  17.1550  21.700   44.573   100
    5   3.226   4.1050   4.85050   4.3990   5.279   13.490   100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using the `x` in the question:

```
 x[[c("a", "b")]]
 ## [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You just made me realize that all those years I totally missed an "R programming 101" way of doing things ;-)